# Practices of MVC3 with AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have worked with MVC/MVC2 and built some web applications based on Nerddinner. Those applications only use webform and entity framework. I would like to start to use more Ajax and looked for some tutroials but they are a bit out of day. Does any one have found some recent practices/examples/tutorials/ of MVC3 with more integration of Ajax?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend book 'Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework' by Steven Sanderson - it have examples of real applications and problems in development in begin, if you want - you can go in more detail chapters with description of all mechanisms, ajax and jquery basics included too. Book available for MVC2. To learn more about mvc 3 - read [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) blog.
For ajax read [JQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery):